# What is the difference between serializing and encoding?

Tags: encoding, service, serialization

What is the difference between serializing and encoding?
When should I use each in a web service?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[Serializing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) is about moving structured data over a storage/transmission medium in a way that the structure can be maintained. [Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code) is more broad, like about how said data is converted to different forms, etc. Perhaps you could think about serializing being a subset of encoding in this example.

With regard to a web service, you will probably be considering serializing/deserializing certain data for making/receiving requests/responses - effectively transporting "messages". Encoding is at a lower level, like how your messaging/web service type/serialization mechanism works under the hood.

Comment: What serialization method does http & tcp use? Or is that not defined by those protocols, and instead left up to the implementation of the client and server software?