# Marshal, Serialization, and Encoding

Tags: php, json, go, encoding, marshalling

In PHP, why is the function to convert a JSON string to a PHP object `json_encode` and in the Go world `Marshal`?

I've been reading the [definitions and differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784143/what-is-the-difference-between-serializing-and-encoding) between marshaling and encoding, and I don't get why Golang would call it different to PHP?

Comment: Preference? Many languages have different names for functions that essentially perform the same operation.

Comment: They are just different names for essentially the same thing. Note also that the json package does have Encoder and Decoder for use with streams.

Answer (score -1):

Different languages call it different things, but they all do the same thing.

```
Go: Marshal
JavaScript: Stringify
Python: Dumps
Php: Encode
```